Google default icon is showing up for a millisecond on marker
I have a lot of markers on the map with custom view, when the markers are added on the map, for a millisecond or so, the default icon of a marker is visible on my custom marker and then my custom marker gets visible. I have an alpha animation as well, attaching the code below:
    private fun setIconToMarkerWithAnimation(m: Marker?, bitmap: Bitmap? = null) {
        val mapIcon = bitmap ?: getBitmapFromMarker(m)
        m?.setIcon(mapIcon?.let { BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(it) })
        val animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.01F, 1.0F)
        animation.duration = MapConstants.DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION
        animation.interpolator = AnticipateOvershootInterpolator()
        animation.addUpdateListener { animationState ->
            val alpha = animationState.animatedValue as Float
            m?.alpha = alpha
        }
        animation.start()
    }

This function is called after this code:
`val m = mMap?.addMarker(markerOptions)`

The problem is not visible on all phones but in some it is visible everytime. Also, I'm removing all previous markers before adding the new ones.
I've tried using
        m?.isVisible = false m?.setIcon(null)
but this is also not helping

Update: The issue was solved when I set the icon to MarkerOptions rather than the marker.
